# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function aq_resize() in shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have taken over administrating a wordpress site. Now i receive an error message when I navigate to a specific page "picture of the month":

> The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your
>   site admin email inbox for instructions.

When I check my debug log I see this:

```
[13-Jun-2019 08:55:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function aq_resize() in /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-content/themes/thepalace/inc/shortcodes.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(325): ap_sc_gallery(Array, '', 'gallery')
#1 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
#2 /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(199): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(galler...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '<p><img class="...')
#3 /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): do_shortcode('<p><img class="...')
#4 /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(208): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<p><img class="...', Array)
#5 /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(1532): apply_filters('the_content', '<img class="ali...')
#6 /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php(473): WP_REST_Posts_Controller->prepare_item_for_response(Object(WP_Post), Object(WP_REST_Request))
#7 /home/mcbri in /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-content/themes/thepalace/inc/shortcodes.php on line 79
```

I am using php version 7.2.

Does anyone have a clue how I could further debug this?

Comment: There should be a plugin called Aqua Resizer. The problem is there. Do you have an active plugin called Aqua Resizer?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I only have 4 plugins installed: Akismet Anti-Spam, Follow Buttons by AddThis, Google XML Sitemaps,  
WordPress Importer

Comment: might be you didn't included the aq_resizer.php file

Comment: The Theme must require that plugin. Or at least one of the other plugins used. Install it and it will work.

Comment: Then it is included (or should be included) to your theme.  Just contact to your theme developers and they will tell you how to solve this.

Comment: I just noticed in my functions.php I require it and the file is there: require_once( get_template_directory() . '/img-resizer/aq_resizer.php' );
But i guess it is not loaded in shortcodes.php as the error says? How would I ensure it is always loaded?

Comment: ah fixed, simply added: 
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/img-resizer/aq_resizer.php' );